# Why wont my List show in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I dont understand why my list wont show up in DataGridView. If i remove the comment for dataGridView1.DataSource = actors.ToList(); it runs... But I need it to run when i press the button_click.   What could be wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }


    public void LoadData()
    {
        List<Actor> actors = new List<Actor>
    {
        new Actor(){ PersonId = 1, ForNavn = "xxxx", EtterNavn = "bbbbb", Adresse = "Hhhhhh", PostNr = 37325, PostSted = "aaaa" },
        new Actor(){ PersonId = 2, ForNavn = "ggggg", EtterNavn = "ddddd", Adresse = "Dssssss", PostNr = 37464, PostSted = "ssfff"  },
    };
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = actors.ToList();
    }


    private void btnSok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Actor> actors = new List<Actor>();

        var query = from actor in actors
                    select actor;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: The actors list is empty, you didn't add any elements to it like you did in LoadData.

Comment: it's preferable to use databinding.

Answer (score 2):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Actor> _actors;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }


    public void LoadData()
    {
        _actors = new List<Actor>
    {
        new Actor(){ PersonId = 1, ForNavn = "xxxx", EtterNavn = "bbbbb", Adresse = "Hhhhhh", PostNr = 37325, PostSted = "aaaa" },
        new Actor(){ PersonId = 2, ForNavn = "ggggg", EtterNavn = "ddddd", Adresse = "Dssssss", PostNr = 37464, PostSted = "ssfff"  },
    };
    }


    private void btnSok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var query = from actor in _actors
                    select actor;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();

    }
}
```

actors in btnsOK was declared again, not loaded and therefore sort of blank.

Answer (score 1):

Because your actors list is empty in the button click event

Use this instead:

```
 List<Actor> actors = new List<Actor>
    {
        new Actor(){ PersonId = 1, ForNavn = "xxxx", EtterNavn = "bbbbb", Adresse = "Hhhhhh", PostNr = 37325, PostSted = "aaaa" },
        new Actor(){ PersonId = 2, ForNavn = "ggggg", EtterNavn = "ddddd", Adresse = "Dssssss", PostNr = 37464, PostSted = "ssfff"  },
    };
```

Comment: What should i write instead of List<Actor> actors = new List<Actor>();
 in the btn_click then? Cause if i remove it says unassigned local variable actors.

Comment: Either load your data in the button click event or use Tony Hopkinson's answer